# Requirejs conflict

Tags: javascript, requirejs, inject

I have next issue. I develop widget for games. So developers give me there game (html+js+css) and I inject my widget to there page. I do it like:

```
<script data-main="/js/entities/pages/pageExternalGame" src="/js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
```

So it works in the most of games. But some developers also using require.js for there purposes, and I get next error on the page:

[image]

How can I handle with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to resolve, may be it will help to someone: 
I'm just taking requirejs that I'm using, and change inside it all "require" and "define" on "requireMy" and "defineMy" - and use it in my code.